# How I register an event to when the user hits done afte entering date on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am using the default time input device in my jQuery Mobile application, which looks like

[image]

How do I register a javascript event to when the user clicks "done" on a mobile device? I have tried blur to no avail.

Comment: You mean "date entry", not "time entry" - right?  At least that's what the image is showing

Comment: Oh, I'm actually using the time input device. However, the date input device is similar. Sorry, I should have been more clear. I have now added my own screenshot of the time input device.

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think you can detect when a user clicks the *done* button. If this is true, you should explore ways to detect other *listanable* changes that happen when the button is pressed, if any exist.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you use blur?

Comment: The alert popup that was supposed to fire did not.

Comment: What happens if you use the `change` event? It's got to fire at some point after the user changes the value, though it may be after the user then blurs the element (taps on something else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/api/events.html) says to look for the method that's passed to the element, then you can check for the close method.

```
$('element').bind('datebox', function (e, passed) { 
  if ( passed.method === 'close' ) {
    alert('test');
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.